# How may one find the primitive of a (non-rational) function of circular functions?

Tags: integration

How may one go about evaluating the $$\int{\frac{1}{\cos^2x}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{\sin 2x}}\,\mathrm d x}$$ using elementary functions alone?

I have tried some substitutions to try to simplify the integrand, but nothing doing. Specifically I used some obvious substitutions and the Weierstrass substitution. However, I got nowhere.

Many thanks.

Comment: Ask [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Ccos%5E2x%7D%5Csqrt%7B1%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Csin+2x%7D%7D).

Comment: @lhf Had done, but it wouldn't let me see the derivation. That's what I'm most interested in. If you have access to this you may post as an answer and I'll be done. :)

Comment: Weierstrass substitution is perfectly suitable to this case.

Comment: @dfnu Either I made an error or I didn't see how. Could you post your work? I ended up with a dreary mess of an integrand. Here, for specificity: $$\frac{(1+t^2)((t-1)^2-2)}{(1-t^2)^2\sqrt{t(1-t^2)}},$$ with $t=\tan\frac x2.$ Needless to say, the mess discouraged me.

Comment: @dfnu Oh, I see now. I should have done a little modification to avoid all the mess. As explained in one of the answers below, the substitution $t=\tan x$ does work very nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us use $\sin 2x=\frac{2\tan x}{1+\tan^2x}$, and $\tan x=t$, the Integral becomes
$$I=\int \frac{1+t}{\sqrt{2t}} dt= \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (t^{-1/2}+t^{1/2}) dt=
\sqrt{2} (\tan^{1/2} x+\frac{1}{3}\tan^{3/2}x)+C. $$
Mathematica gives:
$$-((2 Sqrt[1 + Csc[2 x]] (Cos[x] - Sec[x] - 3 Sin[x]))/(
 3 (Cos[x] + Sin[x])))$$

Answer (score 1):

Note, that $\frac{dx}{cos^2(x)}$ is $d(tan(x))$. Also $sin(2x)=\frac{2tan(x)}{1+tan^2(x)}$. Let $t=tan(x)$. Now the integral reads: $$\int\sqrt{1+\frac{1+t^2}{2t}}dt=\int\frac{t+1}{\sqrt{2t}}dt$$ This evaluates to $\sqrt{2t}(t+3)/3 + C$

Comment: I'm not sure how you define $g(x).$ You say, *Let $t=tg(x)$* somewhere, but I don't think that's what you meant.

Comment: Oh, sorry. It's tan(x) everywhere, where I wrote tg(x). I'm used to this obsolete notation of tangent function. I edit my answer to avoid confusion.

Comment: Oh, I see. I didn't even think $tg$ meant a single entity since $t$ was used separately for something else.